# Servlet Not Sending Form Data to Table

Tags: java, sql, database

I'm creating a java servlet and trying to create a new 'lab'. However, it isn't submitting to the database. Looking at the console when the page loads it prints `JDBC Driver Loaded` and then when submit is clicked it prints out `'got connection'` in the console. When I check the database the information hasn't submitted

The table I'm try to submit to is:

```
lab - id, capacity, day, time, room, subject_id, user_id
```

Here is the code for my servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    /**
     * Servlet implementation class CreateLab
     */
    @WebServlet("/CreateLab")
    public class CreateLab extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public CreateLab() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        private int capacity; 
        private String day = ""; 
        private String time = ""; 
        private String room = ""; 
        private int subject_id;
        private int user_id;

        public void init() {
          try {
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              Connection con =
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wae","root","");
            System.out.println("JDBC driver loaded"); 
          } 
          catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString()); 
          } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        } 

        /**Process the HTTP Get request*/ 
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
      ServletException,IOException {  
          sendPageHeader(response); 
          sendRegistrationForm(request, response, false); 
          sendPageFooter(response); 
        } 

        /**Process the HTTP Post request*/ 
        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
          HttpServletResponse response) 
          throws ServletException, IOException {
          sendPageHeader(response); 


          day = request.getParameter("day"); 
          time = request.getParameter("time"); 
          room = request.getParameter("room"); 



          boolean error = false; 
          String message = null; 
          try {
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              Connection con = 
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wae","root","");
            System.out.println("got connection"); 
            System.out.println(capacity);
            System.out.println(day);
            System.out.println(time);
            System.out.println(room);
            System.out.println(subject_id);
            System.out.println(user_id);
            Statement s = con.createStatement(); 

            String sql = "SELECT id FROM user" + 
                    " WHERE id='" + user_id + "'";  
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql); 
            if (rs.next()) {
              rs.close(); 
               sql = "INSERT INTO lab" + 
                      " (capacity, day, time, room, subject_id, user_id)" + 
                      " VALUES" + 
                      " ('" +  capacity + "'," + 
                         " '"  +  day + "'," + 
                         " '"  +  time + "'," + 
                         " '"  + room + "','" + subject_id +
                         "'," + user_id + "')"; 


              int i = s.executeUpdate(sql); 
              if (i==1) {
                message = "Successfully a new lab class."; 
              } 
            } 
              s.close(); 
              con.close(); 
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) {
              message = "Error." + e.toString(); 
              error = true; 
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
              message = "Error." + e.toString(); 
              error = true; 
            } 
            if (message!=null) {
              PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
              out.println("<B>" + message + "</B><BR>"); 
              out.println("<HR><BR>"); 
            } 
            if (error==true) 
              sendRegistrationForm(request, response, true); 
            else 
              sendRegistrationForm(request, response, false); 
            sendPageFooter(response); 
          } 

          /** 
           * Send the HTML page header, including the title 
           * and the <BODY> tag 
           */ 
          private void sendPageHeader(HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html"); 
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
            out.println("<HTML>"); 
            out.println("<HEAD>"); 
            out.println("<TITLE>Create Lab Page</TITLE>"); 
            out.println("</HEAD>"); 
            out.println("<BODY>"); 
            out.println("<CENTER>"); 
          } 

          /** 
           * Send the HTML page footer, i.e. the </BODY> 
           * and the </HTML> 
           */ 
          private void sendPageFooter(HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
            out.println("</CENTER>"); 
            out.println("</BODY>"); 
            out.println("</HTML>"); 
          }   
          /**Send the form where the user can type in 
           * the details for a new user 
           */ 
          private void sendRegistrationForm(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, boolean displayPreviousValues) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {

            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
            out.println("<BR><H2>Create A Lab</H2>"); 
            out.println("<BR>Please enter the lab details."); 
            out.println("<BR>"); 
            out.println("<BR><FORM METHOD=POST>"); 
            out.println("<TABLE>"); 
            out.println("<TR>"); 
            out.println("<TD>Class Capacity</TD>"); 
            out.print("<TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT Name=capacity"); 

            if (displayPreviousValues) 
              out.print(" VALUE=\"" + capacity + "\""); 

            out.println("></TD>"); 
            out.println("</TR>"); 
            out.println("<TR>"); 
            out.println("<TD>Day</TD>"); 
            out.print("<TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT Name=day"); 

            if (displayPreviousValues) 
              out.print(" VALUE=\"" + day + "\""); 

            out.println("></TD>"); 
            out.println("</TR>"); 
            out.println("<TR>"); 
            out.println("<TD>Time</TD>"); 
            out.print("<TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT Name=time"); 

            if (displayPreviousValues) 
              out.print(" VALUE=\"" + time + "\""); 

            out.println("></TD>"); 
            out.println("</TR>"); 
            out.println("<TR>"); 
            out.println("<TD>Room</TD>"); 
            out.print("<TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT Name=room");
            if (displayPreviousValues) 
                out.print(" VALUE=\"" + room + "\"");
            out.println("></TD>");
            out.println("</TR>");
            out.println("<TR>");
            out.println("<TD>subject_id</TD>");
            out.print("<TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT Name=subject_id");
            if (displayPreviousValues) 
                out.print(" VALUE=\"" + subject_id + "\"");
            out.println("></TD>");
            out.println("</TR>");
            out.println("<TR>");
            out.println("<TD>user_id</TD>");
            out.print("<TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT Name=user_id");
            out.println("></TD>");
            out.println("</TR>");

            if (displayPreviousValues) 
            out.print(" VALUE=\"" + user_id + "\""); 
            out.println("</TD>"); 
            out.println("</TR>");

            out.println("<TR>"); 
            out.println("<TD><INPUT TYPE=RESET></TD>"); 
            out.println("<TD><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT></TD>"); 
            out.println("</TR>"); 
            out.println("</TABLE>"); 
            out.println("</FORM>"); 
            out.println("<BR>"); 
            out.println("<BR>"); 
          }
      }
```

Comment: it might be cuz theres nothing in the result set. try printing the stuff after you execute the select query and check .

Comment: when I go to print out everything after submit is clicked, capacity, user_id and subject_id isn't being grabbed. how can i remedy this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import java.io.IOException;


import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CreateLab
 */
@WebServlet("/CreateLab")
public class CreateLab extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public CreateLab() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

     int capacity; 
     String day = ""; 
     String time = ""; 
     String room = ""; 
     int subject_id;
     int user_id;

    public void init() {
      try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          Connection con =
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wae","root","");
        System.out.println("JDBC driver loaded"); 
      } 
      catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString()); 
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    } 

    /**Process the HTTP Get request*/ 
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
  ServletException,IOException {  
      sendPageHeader(response); 
      sendRegistrationForm(request, response, false); 
      sendPageFooter(response); 
    } 

    /**Process the HTTP Post request*/ 
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response) 
      throws ServletException, IOException {
      sendPageHeader(response); 

      capacity = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("capacity")); 
      day = request.getParameter("day"); 
      time = request.getParameter("time"); 
      room = request.getParameter("room"); 
      user_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("user_id")); 
      subject_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("subject_id")); 


      boolean error = false; 
      String message = null; 
      try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          Connection con = 
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wae","root","");
        System.out.println("got connection"); 
        System.out.println(capacity);
        System.out.println(day);
        System.out.println(time);
        System.out.println(room);
        System.out.println(subject_id);
        System.out.println(user_id);
        Statement s = con.createStatement(); 

        String sql = "SELECT id FROM user" + 
                " WHERE id='" + user_id + "'";  
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql); 
        if (rs.next()) {
          rs.close(); 
           sql = "INSERT INTO lab" + 
                  " (capacity, day, time, room, subject_id, user_id)" + 
                  " VALUES" + 
                  " ('" +  capacity + "'," + 
                     " '"  +  day + "'," + 
                     " '"  +  time + "'," + 
                     " '"  + room + "','" + subject_id + "','" + user_id + "')"; 

          System.out.println(sql);
          int i = s.executeUpdate(sql); 
          if (i==1) {
            message = "Successfully a new lab class."; 
          } 
        } 
          s.close(); 
          con.close(); 
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
          message = "Error." + e.toString(); 
          error = true; 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
          message = "Error." + e.toString(); 
          error = true; 
        } 
        if (message!=null) {
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
          out.println("<B>" + message + "</B><BR>"); 
          out.println("<HR><BR>"); 
        } 
        if (error==true) 
          sendRegistrationForm(request, response, true); 
        else 
          sendRegistrationForm(request, response, false); 
        sendPageFooter(response); 
      } 

      /** 
       * Send the HTML page header, including the title 
       * and the <BODY> tag 
       */ 
      private void sendPageHeader(HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html"); 
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
        out.println("<HTML>"); 
        out.println("<HEAD>"); 
        out.println("<TITLE>Create Lab Page</TITLE>"); 
        out.println("</HEAD>"); 
        out.println("<BODY>"); 
        out.println("<CENTER>"); 
      } 

      /** 
       * Send the HTML page footer, i.e. the </BODY> 
       * and the </HTML> 
       */ 
      private void sendPageFooter(HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
        out.println("</CENTER>"); 
        out.println("</BODY>"); 
        out.println("</HTML>"); 
      }   
      /**Send the form where the user can type in 
       * the details for a new user 
       */ 
      private void sendRegistrationForm(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, boolean displayPreviousValues) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
        out.println("<BR><H2>Create A Lab</H2>"); 
        out.println("<BR>Please enter the lab details."); 
        out.println("<BR>"); 
        out.println("<BR><FORM METHOD=POST>"); 
        out.println("<TABLE>"); 
        out.println("<TR>"); 
        out.println("<TD>Class Capacity</TD>"); 
        out.print("<TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT Name=capacity"); 

        if (displayPreviousValues) 
          out.print(" VALUE=\"" + capacity + "\""); 

        out.println("></TD>"); 
        out.println("</TR>"); 
        out.println("<TR>"); 
        out.println("<TD>Day</TD>"); 
        out.print("<TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT Name=day"); 

        if (displayPreviousValues) 
          out.print(" VALUE=\"" + day + "\""); 

        out.println("></TD>"); 
        out.println("</TR>"); 
        out.println("<TR>"); 
        out.println("<TD>Time</TD>"); 
        out.print("<TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT Name=time"); 

        if (displayPreviousValues) 
          out.print(" VALUE=\"" + time + "\""); 

        out.println("></TD>"); 
        out.println("</TR>"); 
        out.println("<TR>"); 
        out.println("<TD>Room</TD>"); 
        out.print("<TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT Name=room");
        if (displayPreviousValues) 
            out.print(" VALUE=\"" + room + "\"");
        out.println("></TD>");
        out.println("</TR>");
        out.println("<TR>");
        out.println("<TD>subject_id</TD>");
        out.print("<TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT Name=subject_id");
        if (displayPreviousValues) 
            out.print(" VALUE=\"" + subject_id + "\"");
        out.println("></TD>");
        out.println("</TR>");
        out.println("<TR>");
        out.println("<TD>user_id</TD>");
        out.print("<TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT Name=user_id");
        out.println("></TD>");
        out.println("</TR>");

        if (displayPreviousValues) 
        out.print(" VALUE=\"" + user_id + "\""); 
        out.println("</TD>"); 
        out.println("</TR>");

        out.println("<TR>"); 
        out.println("<TD><INPUT TYPE=RESET></TD>"); 
        out.println("<TD><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT></TD>"); 
        out.println("</TR>"); 
        out.println("</TABLE>"); 
        out.println("</FORM>"); 
        out.println("<BR>"); 
        out.println("<BR>"); 
      }
      }
```

Comment: you should add your comments on what you've done to get your problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you never assign your `subject_id`, other than initializing it to `0` when declaring it. It looks like you have it as a form field so maybe you want to extract it from the request like you do with `day`, `time` and `room`. I confess I don't understand the logic of the implementation either (only create a lab if one already exists for that subject), but that's neither here nor there.

A few points of feedback on your code.

1. Servlets are not thread-bound. One instance of a servlet class can be used to handle multiple concurrent requests for the same URL. As such, you need to take thread safety into consideration. Your code is definitely **not** thread-safe as you are using instance variables (`capacity`, `day`, `time` etc) in your service methods.
2. Printing HTML in Java code is not really how it's done these days. At minimum, you should always forward to a JSP page to render the view. More common is to use one of the many MVC or component based web frameworks out there (Spring, Struts, JSF, etc, etc, etc).
3. Use valid HTML. For instance, there is no such thing as `<input type=int ...>`. See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: i updated my code, in regards to point 2 - I'm just trying to get the functionality working before I try forwarding to a jsp to render the view. we are currently doing a uni assignment that requires the use of jsp/servlets and java beans. After changing my code to fit with your recommendations it still isn't creating a new instance of a lab in the database when user.id=lab.user_id.

Comment: Again, you are never reading the user_id from the request. You need to invoke something like `user_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("user_id"));`.

Comment: i fixed it, will post the answer in 2 seconds